# How to optimise the following method

Tags: ruby, optimization

I am working with ruby and the idea is to create a method that adds all prime numbers below a given value. What I have works for now but when i use bigger numbers like 10 million, it takes forever to run. I was wondering if there was a way I could optimise the code below to make it run faster even with such big numbers

```
def self.sum_to(limit)
  primes = (2..limit).select do |n|
    (2..Math.sqrt(n)).none? do |i|
       (n % i).zero?
    end
  end

  sum = primes.reduce(:+)
end

puts Primes.sum_to(10000000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby 1.9 has a built-in Prime class that you could use:

```
require 'prime'
Prime.take_while{|p| p < limit}.reduce(:+)
```